# Use outer join or wrap second context call in where clause?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have formulated two queries which return the same result. The datasets to be queried in the wild will be large. The outer join query is more verbose in C# but I am pretty sure it is more performant than the second option, which wraps a context call with predicate in a where clause; Am I right in my assumption?

Outer Join:

```
var queryOuter = Context.Foo
            .GroupJoin(Context.Bar, foo => foo.Id, bar => bar.fooId,
            (foo, bar) => new
            {
                Foo = foo,
                Bar = bar
            })
            .SelectMany(fb => fb.Bar.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
            (fb, bar) => new
            {
                Foo = sr.Foo,
                Bar = bar
            })
            .Where(fb => fb.Bar == null)
            .Select(fb => fb.Foo)
            .Where(myPredicate);
```

Versus:

```
var query = Context.Foo.Where(foo => !Context.Bar.Any(bar => bar.fooId == foo.Id))
            .Where(myPredicate);
```

Comment: Try it and measure the time. Maybe it already create quiet similiar SQL.

Comment: @Holger - Well, I have been but just with mock data and that does not give any useful feedback owing to tiny dataset, to test it in production is a no-no.

Comment: just compare the SQL, first with your eyes, than with SQL profiler. You get an idea of  what's going on. Probably both is a left outer join.Just the length of the SQL generated, will tell you a story.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for this suggestion it has answered my question. I used Linqpad and the results are quite convincing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linqpad, as suggested, and connecting to my dev DB (after adding significant quantity of mock data) - I have answered this question with the following findings:

Using an outer join generated the following SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].*
FROM [Foo] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[FooId]
FROM [Bar] AS [t1]) 
AS [t2] ON [t0].[Id] = [t2].[FooId]
WHERE (NOT ([t0].[SomeBool] = 1)) 
AND ([t0].[SomeDate] IS NOT NULL) 
AND (NOT ([t0].[SomeOtherDate] IS NOT NULL)) 
AND ([t2].[test] IS NULL)
```

Using context call with predicate in where clause generated the following SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].*
FROM [Foo] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [Bar] AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[FooId] = [t0].[Id]))) 
AND (NOT ([t0].[SomeBool] = 1)) 
AND ([t0].[SomeDate] IS NOT NULL) 
AND ([t0].[SomeOtherDate] IS NULL)
```

- Outer join execution time: 0.681s
- Predicate on Table (context): 1.068s

I cannot explain with certainty why but, as I suspected, the query employing the outer join is significantly faster (157%).  My guess is that it executes two queries in effect instead of one; one on Foo and then performs the query on Bar in the where clause, whereas the outer join performs one query on predefined parameters.